# Looking to display a text RSS feed as Windows 7 desktop/background

Tags: windows-7, windows, desktop, rss, desktop-customization

I'd like to display an RSS feed (updating dynamically of course) on my Windows 7 desktop.  The posts I've read about Windows 7 RSS backgrounds are all about displaying various background images delivered via RSS.  What I'm looking for would be similar to the Windows XP/95 Active Desktop feature which allowed for web pages to be presented on the desktop background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an application like [Rainmeter + skins](http://lifehacker.com/5332071/rainmeter-10-brings-the-enigma-desktop-to-everyone) to have RSS feed updated dynamically and display as background.